# Объявление двумерного массива и обращение к его элементам через указатель

Tags: c, массивы, указатели, динамические-массивы, malloc

Может кто подсказать, как создать двумерный массив, выделяя память через `malloc()`, и как тогда обращаться к элементам через указатель?

Answer (score 0):

Например, для `n` строк и `m` столбцов:

```
int ** matrix = malloc(n*sizeof(int*));
for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    matrix[i] = malloc(m*sizeof(int));
```

Ну, соответственно, нужно корректно освободить память при выходе.

Обращение - обычное `matrix[i][j]` или  `*(*(matrix+i)+j)`.

Не компилировал, но вроде нигде сильно не ошибся...

Заполнять -

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    for(int j = 0; j < m; ++j)
        scanf("%d",&matrix[i][j]);
```

Comment: А можно его заполнять как одномерный? Например for... scanf("%d", *(a+i));?

Comment: @Алексей Я же уже запретил Вам это делать! https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/894353/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2

Comment: @Igor отстаньте уже от меня)

Comment: Как одномерный - можно, @Igor вам по указанной ссылке рассказывал, как.. Но это совсем другая история!